# Data Inserted, Updated or Deleted in MS Access not directly available

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, insert, refresh

My app in VB.Net loads data from MS Access in a datagridview (bound with a BindingSource, but result/problem is the same if that's a DataTable).

```
Private Sub LecturesPrestations()

        Dim myConnection = New OleDbConnection(S7ConnString)
        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            Requete = "SELECT s.ID, u.Nom, s.DatePresta, s.TimeIn, s.TimeOut, IIF(s.TimeOut IS NULL, NULL, CDATE(s.TimeOut - s.TimeIn)) AS Duree, s.Description " &
                      "FROM SAV_Prestas AS s " &
                      "INNER JOIN Users AS u ON u.ID = s.UserID " &
                      "WHERE s.NumRMA = " & monRetour.ID & ";"
            Call GetBindingSource(Requete, bsPrestas, RequeteOK)
            If Not RequeteOK Then
                MsgBox("Problème de lecture des données",, "Chargement des prestations")
            Else
                With Me.dgvPresta
                    .DataSource = bsPrestas
                    ...
```

We can then insert, delete or modifiy a row in this dgv by explicit Access instructions (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE...). The dgv is then refreshed (reload), to include these modifications.

```
    Private Sub tsmiSuppression_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsmiSuppression.Click

        If dgvPresta.CurrentCell IsNot Nothing Then
            Requete = "DELETE * FROM SAV_Prestas WHERE ID = " & CInt(dgvPresta.Item("ID", dgvPresta.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value.ToString)
            RequeteSQL(Requete, RequeteOK)
            If Not RequeteOK Then
                MsgBox("La prestation n'a pas pu être supprimée.")
            Else
                Call LecturesPrestations()
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Sélectionnez une prestation.", vbOKOnly, vbInformation)
        End If

    End Sub
```

```
    Public Sub RequeteSQL(ByVal Request As String, ByRef Resultat As Boolean, Optional ByRef MsgErreur As String = Nothing)

        Dim myConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(S7ConnString)
        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim myCommand = New OleDbCommand(Request, myConnection)
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Resultat = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Resultat = False
            MsgErreur = ex.Message
        Finally
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

In this way, the dgv does not display the modified data (example: deleted data still appears). It is only after a new "refresh" a few seconds later that the modifications appear.

Have you any idea what's wrong and how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens in RequeteSQL? Where is RequeteOK set to True? Does `Call LecuresPrestations()` run?

Comment: I've modified my post to include RequeteSQL. Both GetBindingSource and RequeteSQL return RequeteOK at True. So LecturePrestations is reload.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to refresh your datagridview after SQL Query?

Call dgvPresta.refresh() after "Call LecturesPrestations()"

Connection performance to your DB and size might be the problem.